# Spaceship from a film or show that is semi circular in shape with a section jutting out of the middle

Tags: movie, tv, spaceship, object-identification

I was out with friends last night and we went into a sci-fi bar where they have props and models all over the place. We had fun identifying all the ships, costumes and stuff, but one model had us stumped, and the person behind the bar wouldn't tell us, saying we'd have to find out by other means, and there would be a free drink in it for us if we could - apparently only one person has ever correctly guessed it in two years.

Unfortunately my mad Googling ran the battery down on my phone so I couldn't get a photo, but I quickly whipped this fairly close approximation of it on my iPad when I got home. I think the curved end is the front and I'm fairly certain it's not: a Cylon vessel, Dengar's ship, anything from *Independence Day*, *Dune* or *StarGate*, not Space 1999 or UFO, not any of the *Aliens* or *Star Wars* films, or *Manta Force*.

[image: Drawing of the ship in question]

I have found a photo of it online (someone asking the exact same question over 6 years ago - never got an answer). As you can see it's a lot more "blocky" than some of the other answers, which are close, but sadly not right...

[image: Image of the actual ship on the ceiling]

Looking on the [virtual tour for the Manchester bar](http://www.fabcafe.co.uk/index.php/content/look-inside.html) we can see a few other low quality images of the ship.

[image: Side view of the ship] [image: Side view of the other side of the ship] [image: Front view of the ship]

Comment: The [Protector](https://galaxyquest.fandom.com/wiki/Protector) from _Galaxy Quest_ is somewhat similar but it has part of the middle bit protruding out the front.

Comment: Were any hints given as to what it could be? I.e. was it from a TV show or movie? Any hints on the year it would be from? etc.

Comment: The barmaid would give no clues at all - said it was more than her job's worth as there was a round of drinks in it!

From the look of it, I think it was from a late 70s or early 80s film or show but I could be wrong. I just got that vibe from it. It had a very hand made feel about it with bits from model kits glues all over it to create detail - much like how they used to do the miniatures on Doctor Who or the original Star Wars films. The thing is like 4 feet across, I think it might actually have been a shooting model.

Comment: Is there a chance it's not actually complete but only part of something?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - my thought is that the back appears complete but that the front could connect to something that sticks out.

Comment: I checked out ships from the Gamma quadrant in DS9 and I think we can rule those out. The Farscape fandom wiki has lots of ships listed and pictured but none like that. Were there any ships from video games, as far as you know? Just wondering if that’s a possible source. Like Wing Commander or something.

Comment: From the looks of it, my guess would be low budget 80s scifi.

Comment: "Found this on a website about the **Fab Cafe in Manchester**: "There is a space ship above you as you walk in that is a bit of a mystery and if you can guess which **TV series** it was in you get a free round of drinks!" " - [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/scifi/comments/1gxcnk/can_anyone_tell_me_where_this_spaceship_model_is/) - So prob 70s/80s ***UK*** TV series. - What else is there besides *Dr. Who* and *Tripods*?

Comment: Google image search using the photograph just suggests "Ceiling" and shows other ceilings I may be interested in :(

Comment: @Mazura Red Dwarf, Blakes Seven, Thunderbirds, Quatermass, The Tomorrow People, UFO, Space 1999, Star Cops, Terrahawks... I can go on 

Comment: Yep, that's the place @Mazura - I was keeping the location quiet in case anyone claimed the free round ahead of me :p

Comment: Can you take some pictures from different angles?  That would hopefully allow Google to bring back some other results other than 'ceiling' . Amazing that is the only picture from that that pub on the internet.

Comment: Of course its possible that it was just a model someone made, has never been on TV or film, and the round of drinks is impossible to get.

Comment: Is it definitely a spaceship? It looks like it could be a building (mounted upside-down on the ceiling) from a prison planet or industrial colony or military base.

Comment: @alemus - There are other pictures. This is merely the highest resolution.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it's from a Gerry Anderson production. That'd tie in with the name of the cafe. https://www.gerryanderson.co.uk/question/what-does-fab-stand-for/ OTOH, a Google image search doesn't turn up a match, so I guess the name's a red herring.

Comment: I wonder if it's a smoke alarm (or some other sort of danger sensor) in disguise. It appears to be connected to the room's fire sprinkler system.

Comment: assuming they have hung it to show the side with the most detail we might actually be looking at it the wring way up... i wonder if it would help if we flipped the image 180 degrees?

Comment: For those wanting to see the ship from more angles, that pub does a virtual tour. The lighting isn't great, but you can see the model from multiple angles. Go to http://www.fabcafe.co.uk/ and click on the virtual tour for Manchester

Comment: I tried finding similar looks here on this 'poster' https://www.deviantart.com/dirkloechel/art/Size-Comparison-Science-Fiction-Spaceships-398790051, but unable to find anything. My initial though was something Hitchhikers Guide to the Galaxy, Red Dwarf or Farscape. Though still unable to find anything. (Feel bad for the Cafe though, once this is answered they are gonna be hurting :P )

Comment: @Brian A Google image search of the reddit image tell me "maritime museum."

Comment: I am now reading all Yelp reviews on this cafe in the hope someone left the answer there.

Comment: the middle bit looks like a face or a skull. Thundercats or Skeletor from He man? Dunno. Probably from cartoon and not live action show.

Comment: Now that we can see how it’s mounted, I also believe this is an/the original production model. That would suggest it is from a live action production and that the show was made in the UK. I also agree now that it’s not clear which is the front and which is the back. I hope it’s not from some obscure Doctor Who episode - that might be hard to track down.

Comment: I’m sad that offering a bounty didn’t magically get us an answer. Seems like we’ve had a lot of eyeballs here and no one knows it.

Comment: I'm going to guess its after 1960's (due to coloring and shape) and before 2000's given that props stopped being used in place of cgi around this time. Checked into past events that might have included this as theatrical prop at the location with no success. Also, compared it visually to 500 of the most popular with no luck here: https://sparksradio.com/2017/09/every-spaceship/ Finally, I cropped the imaged and ran searches on bing, google and TinEye with no similar results. At this point you would have to binge watch sci fi series during that time period to find it I think.

Comment: The old 1978 show Project U.F.O. supposedly went through tons of spaceship models, but I can't a way to see what any of them were.

Comment: There is also a StarWars spaceship called Ebon Hawk that has some resemblance so could it be a variation of that? Idk cause I haven't watched all starwars products (cartoon,videogames) but maybe someone has.

Comment: I don't think its star wars, the coloring and shape isn't consistent with any culture or species I'm familiar with (but then I'm assuming this was not a beta model).

Comment: Contacted the owners, as it is an ongoing 'event' they wouldn't provide any hints at all.

Comment: Interestingly, it's been at both of their locations, or possibly two halves of a single circular ship. Either way, it's not clear which side is up and which side is down; https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN7cT.jpg

Comment: Arewe sure it's a TV- or movie prop? Could it have been featured in a space-based RPG, like Traveller for instance? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traveller_(role-playing_game)

Comment: On this site https://www.reddit.com/r/spaceships/comments/1gwjap/can_anyone_tell_me_what_this_spaceship_model_is/caprjaq/?context=8&depth=9 a comment thread indicates the model was specifically made for the Cafe.  If true, would indicate Paul Johnson's comment on 21 Sept 2019 was an accurate guess.

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR It was made specifically for the [Fab Cafe](http://www.fabcafe.co.uk/) in Manchester.

A Google image search provided this link to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/spaceships/comments/1gwjap/can_anyone_tell_me_what_this_spaceship_model_is/) which someone had also inquired about the model. Two peoples' responses make these claims:

Person 1:                                                         6 years ago

> SOLVED: This model was specifically made for Fab Cafe and has been on exhibit since opening day.
>   Source: Friend of one of the owners. I tried emailing the cafe, but got no reply. Posted the image in a Facebook forum of special effects artists, and voila!

Person 2:                                                         6 years ago

> This is correct.
>   Source: Used to work there.

Comment: Of course my answer is not definitive proof. Just passing on what I was able to find on my own.

Comment: I found this reddit post initially and someone posted it as a comment as well. It's likely the best we'll get but as you say it's not necessarily true.

Comment: Ah, just came back to see if anyone found this ship. Glad that my mind can now rest in peace :D

Comment: boo to the bar for such a scammy bit if true

Answer (score -6):

Could it be a [D'Kora class Ferengi ship](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/D%27Kora_class), from *Star Trek*?

[image: D'Kora class Ferengi ship graphic]

Comment: One of the guys with us thought Ferengi, but it's not that - it's a kind of pewter/grey color, whereas the Ferengi ship is orange. Thanks though :~)

Comment: Plus the rear is entirely wrong

Comment: @Valorum: Not to mention the bow, which isn't even there on the OP's sketch.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - The model *could* be missing the front part. The images just aren't clear

Comment: Front curve of the hull is wrong though: the D'Kora comes to an edge in the concave curve, the ship in the photo is flat.